fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory on Eclipse-based IDE
I am using Momentics IDE in Windows 10, and I need to draw some plots using matplot++. I have copied matplotlibcpp.h to my work directory, and then I got the infamous
Python.h: No such file or directory

while trying to run a simple code
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
    plt::plot({1,3,2,4});
    plt::show();
}

error. I have changed the line in matplotlibcpp.h  from
#include <Python.h>

to
#include <C:\Python\Python312\include\Python.h>

And similarly, I changed the line
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

int
#include <C:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\arrayobject.h>

But now I am getting the following error:
C:\Python\Python312\include\pyconfig.h:59:10: fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory

I checked the other solutions, but all of them are for Visual Studio. I am using an IDE based on Eclipse. What am I missing?

Have you followed the installation instruction of the library you want to use? It clearly says you also need to install Python dev library and link it into your project.

"What am I missing?" The fact that compilers have -I command line switch?

@Yksisarvinen Yes, I have the Python dev library and I have included it into the environment variable in IDE

What is your target, QNX or Windows? If it's QNX then you need to install a Python version targeted at QNX as well. The installation you try to use is targeted for Windows.

@Someprogrammerdude The IDE already has the python library

And is it the one installed in C:\Python? Or does the IDE install its Python somewhere else?

@Someprogrammerdude After two whole days, I realized that QNX does not support simple plot graphics. So, I gave up on this question
